# Class Setup errors with Android version 18

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have two errors that I think relate to the same issue, so I'm posting this as a single question. If there are multiple causes, I can repost as two questions.

Both of these two lines preceding the class declaration have errors.

```
import android.security.KeyPairGeneratorSpec; 
//The import android.security.KeyPairGeneratorSpec cannot be resolved

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
//JELLY_BEAN_MR2 cannot be resolved or is not a field

public class AndroidKeyStoreUtil {

...

}
```

In my manifest, I have this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

I'm current on my SDK installations up through API 19 and I'm compiling with Java 1.6. Do the newer Android APIs require Java 7, maybe? I can't get that to work in Eclipse.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: which version of android are you using to compile? which is your API target?

Comment: check your min and max SDK versions in menifest, max should be at least 18 or higher

Comment: first check do you have API Level 18 SDK?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I've updated my post to answer these questions.

Comment: what is your IDE and when you get an errors? Compilation i assume?

Comment: I'm working in Eclipse (ADT, actually). I get the error as soon as I type either of those lines into the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled on the solution to this. The suggestions of others are definitely required. Specifically, make sure that you have the manifest set to target sdk of 18 (or higher) and also make sure that your Android SDK Manager is current on all updates.

But what was still not solving it for me was simply that I need to update my Project Build Target to at least 4.3 (I was still on 4.2.2). Here is how to do this:

```
Right-click on the project and select Properties
Click Android
Change Build Target to Android 4.3 (or higher)
```

Simple fix once I noticed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in my case I had the sdk target/min correctly setup:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I'm working on an Android-Maven project but the same solution may apply to other types of projects. In my case the problem happened because of wrong dependency. I was using the android dependency provided by Maven Central Repository (which is older than the one I need):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So I used the [Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to get the API 19 one and changed my dependency to:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2_r3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```